# Python filter/lambda

Tags: python, encryption, filter, lambda, keyword

Trying to create a keyword cipher and Ive come across this,I know that it makes the string upper case and remove things like spaces commas and parentheses.I've tried removing it and my code doesnt work, I just want to know how I can remove this successfully

```
from itertools import   starmap,cycle                                                           

def encrypt(message, key):                                                                     

    # convert to uppercase.                                                                    
    # strip out non-alpha characters.                                                          
    message = filter(lambda _: _.isalpha(), message.upper())                                   

    # single letter encrpytion.                                                                
    def enc(c,k): return chr(((ord(k) + ord(c)) % 26) + ord('A'))                              

    return "".join(starmap(enc, zip(message, cycle(key))))                                     

def decrypt(message, key):                                                                     

    # single letter decryption.                                                                
    def dec(c,k): return chr(((ord(c) - ord(k)) % 26) + ord('A'))                              

    return "".join(starmap(dec, zip(message, cycle(key))))

text = input("Enter the message you want to crypt: ")     
key =  input("Enter the key you would like to use: ")                                                                       

encr = encrypt(text, key)                                                                      
decr = decrypt(encr, key)                                                                      

print (text)                                                                                     
print (encr)                                                                                   
print (decr)
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you have some test cases that you've tried?

Comment: Sorry for unclear question,first time using the site.Basically it filters out non alphanumeric characters and makes the string upper case and I dont want this but whatever I try when it decrypts the enrypted phrase the outcome is not the original phrase like it does in this current setup

Comment: you have crazy stuff in there ... do you know what all those functions do? ie `starmap`,`zip`,`chr`,`ord`,`cycle`

Comment: `re.sub('[^A-Z]','',my_text.upper())` ...maybe

Answer (score 1):

Your error can be observed by looking at this line:

```
def enc(c,k): return chr(((ord(k) + ord(c)) % 26) + ord('A'))
```

This function exploits character codes to encrypt the result. Since it uses modulo 26, and adds `ord('A')` it is specialized for upper case letters. One way to rewrite the encryption/decryption if you don't mind unreadable encrypted strings is:

```
from itertools import cycle

def encrypt(message,key):
    def encryptLetter(letterKey):
        letter,key=letterKey
        return chr(ord(letter)+ord(key))
    keySeq=cycle(key)
    return "".join(map(encryptLetter,zip(message,keySeq)))

def decrypt(message,key):
    def decryptLetter(letterKey):
        letter,key=letterKey
        return chr(ord(letter)-ord(key))
    keySeq=cycle(key)
    return "".join(map(decryptLetter,zip(message,keySeq)))
```

Obviously this isn't secure at all...

Comment: Thanks for the help,it's for a school project so it doesnt have to be uncrackable I just have to show it functions

Comment: @pezza if your interested in more awesome crypto, then just google RSA. Its easier than you may think :)